# Plot number of observations for categorical groups

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a data frame that looks like -

```
id      age_bucket          state           gender       duration       category1        is_active
1         (40, 70]     Jammu and Kashmir      m             123           ABB                1
2         (17, 24]       West Bengal          m             72            ABB                0
3         (40, 70]         Bihar              f            109            CA                 0
4         (17, 24]         Bihar              f             52            CA                 1
5         (24, 30]         MP                 m             23            ACC                1
6         (24, 30]         AP                 m             103           ACC                1
7         (30, 40]         West Bengal        f             182           GF                 0
```

I want to create a bar plot with how many people are active for each age_bucket and state (top 10). For for gender and category1 I want to create a pie chart with the proportion of active people. The top of the bar should display the total count for active and inactive members and similarly % should be display on pie chart based on is_active.

How to do it in python using seaborn or matplotlib?

I have done so far -

```
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline 

sns.barplot(x='age_bucket',y='is_active',data=df)

sns.barplot(x='category1',y='is_active',data=df)
```

Comment: You tagged it with matplotlib so what have you tried so far? Using pyplot would make it much easier, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to count the observations rather than plotting a value from a column along the yaxis. In seaborn, the function for this is `countplot()`:

```
sns.countplot('age_bucket', hue='is_active', data=df)
```

[image]

Since the returned object is a matplotlib axis, you could assign it to a variable (e.g. `ax`) and then use [`ax.annotate`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html) to place text in the the figure manually:

```
ax = sns.countplot('age_bucket', hue='is_active', data=df)
ax.annotate('1      1', (0, 1), ha='center', va='bottom', fontsize=12)
```

[image]

Seaborn has no way of creating pie charts, so you would need to [use matplotlib directly](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pie.html). However, it is often easier to tell counts and proportions from bar charts so I would generally recommend that you stick to those unless you have a specific constraint that forces you to use a pie chart.